# Localization in ember-pikaday

Tags: ember.js

How can we apply localization to [ember-pikaday addon](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday) ?

I followed the steps described in their [README](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday#localization) but the months are still displayed in English. I've even open an [issue](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday/issues/187) but it has no responses yet.

Comment: make sure your two initializers run in the right order or only make 1. maybe check if the `i18n` object you pass to `application.register` contains the right translations. make sure the `moment` locale is set when you access the `moment.localeData()._months`!

Answer (score 0):

In my app i do it by instance-initializer (settings for Polish language):

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import moment from 'moment';

export default {
    name: 'setup-pikaday-i18n',
    initialize: function(application) {
        var i18n = Ember.Object.extend({
            previousMonth: 'Poprzedni miesiąc',
            nextMonth: 'Następny miesiąc',
            months: ['Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec','Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień'],
            weekdays: moment.localeData()._weekdays,
            weekdaysShort: moment.localeData()._weekdaysShort
        });

        application.register('pikaday-i18n:main', i18n, { singleton: true });
        application.inject('component:pikaday-input', 'i18n', 'pikaday-i18n:main');
    }
};
```

and ember-moment config is in config/environment.js:

```
let ENV = {

    ......

    moment: {
      includeLocales: ['pl']
    },

    .....
  };
```

Comment: Me too, I defined `setup-pikaday-i18n.js` in `initializers` directory as explained in [ember-pikaday localization](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday#localization) section. Once I put it in `instance-initializers` directory as you did, it worked. I'll update the [issue](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday/issues/187) I opened. Thank you, Karol !